# Live Data in View Model Using Room Database

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am trying to add a view model to my android Recycler View which fetches data from my room database. But I have this error in my kotlin code.

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Observer<in List<>!>
Found:
() → Unit
```

[image: code with the error]

Comment: Add codes of viewmodel and where you get error instead of images.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: here is link to the project's repository https://github.com/denbo12/ContactList.git